# Redirect to url within another url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I have a problem, I need to redirect users to a URL within a url.

For example:
When the user visits the URL: **api.example.com/redirect/www.google.com**

I want the user to be redirected to: **www.google.com**

I've been trying for a while now, but no sucess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like that:

Variant for the main http server configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/redirect/(.+)$ http://$1 [L,R=301]
```

Variant for a `.htaccess` style file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^redirect/(.+)$ http://$1 [L,R=301]
```

It obviously requires the rewrite module being available inside your local http server.

In general you should prefer putting such rules into the main server configuration, *if you have access to that*. A `.htaccess` style file should only be used if you have no other alternative. The reason is that such files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and really slow the http server down.

---

A more robust approach would be to take the captured part of the url and hand it over to a script on the server side as a parameter. The script can validate the part, whether it is a valid "url" (to keep things simple here...). And maybe make a head request to check of the target exists and is usable. Only then it redirects. Otherwise it returns a meaningful error message.

Comment: That's not going to work correctly in .htaccess because it won't match in per directory context. Either remove the leading `/` or make it optional. `^/?redirect/(.+)$ ...`

Comment: @PanamaJack What you say is correct, indeed. Thanks for pointing that out. I modified the answer accordingly.